# GoogleMap V3 Hybrid MapType show as Label under Satellite

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show 3 map type controls: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid'] on GoogleMap in my website, but it always show only 'roadmap', and 'satellite' with a checkbox 'Label' under 'satellite' as dropdown menu.

Here is the code:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid'],
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
    }
  });
}
```

How can I show 3 of them(map type controls) in a row on google map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [custom control](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls) for the hybrid-mapType

Comment: Is there any other possibility?